# state get null after disptach

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using redux in my react native project and I get this error when dispatched sth.

## error:

> TaskQueue: Error with a task: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Tried to get the frame for out of range index NaN

extra information which I prefer to say is that I have navigation with the first screen has connected to *that list and the second screen is connected to *room_Messages

## My Reducer:

```
case 'RECEIVE_MESSAGE':
        {
            index=0;
            msg = JSON.parse(action.msg)


            msgItem = {
                id: Math.random(),
                message: msg.message
            }

            return {...state,
                chatList: {
                    ...state.chatList  
                    , [0]: {
                        ...state.chatList[0], room_messages: {
                            ...state.chatList[0].room_messages.slice(0)
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
```

when I navigate to the second screen and then dispatch  RECEIVE_MESSAGE action, in the first screen my props get null(i noticed this in componentDidUpdate of the first screen)

Comment: could you please post more from your code?